# (Python3) FLASK ADMIN: It is possible to full utilise the table to view data

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

[image]I have recently start working on flask. Flask admin is similar version of django admin as they say.

**My question is can we stretch out table width to remove horizontal scrolling. Also it could help to see data in first glance**.

Please ignore poor editing. **Is it possible to use red area shown in image for table view**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it.
There's **FLASK_ADMIN_FLUID_LAYOUT** config which need to set True. And it enables full fluid layout

```
app.name = 'App Name'
app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_FLUID_LAYOUT'] = True
```

Use above lines to set or unset FLUID_LAYOUT

Comment: Sorry, where and how to add this config?

Comment: I had used config object where I have set it as  "FLASK_ADMIN_FLUID_LAYOUT = True"

Comment: Thanks, may I know which file exactly? Also can you please provide a code snippet to show the exact command? (sorry I am a total noob with flask...)

Comment: @JejeBelfort

app.name = 'App Name'
app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_FLUID_LAYOUT'] = True

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, you get my +1!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! +1  working fine :)

I add in **config.py** this line below:

```
    FLASK_ADMIN_FLUID_LAYOUT = True
```

and the **config.py** is read when app is defined:

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object('config')
```